# Is it possible to restore an entire Windows 7 operating system without image backup?

Tags: windows-7

Some three months back I was happily running a Windows 7. It contained highly important files of mine as well as web searches. But accidentally got formatted I never forsaw the need to create an image backup because I never thought this might happen and partly I used to think that Windows 7 makes automatic image backups; yes, okay. I am an idiot.

Is there anyway to recover an entire OS without image backup? Is there any good data recovery software that might be able to recover an entire OS?

Here is what I did, I Clean installed (full format) Windows 7 then at a later date Upgraded to Windows 10.

Comment: Did you use quick format or full format, did you write anything else on your disk after format?

Comment: Well I Did Install New Windows 7 Which I Have Now Upgraded To Windows 10.It Was Full Format BTW (Trust Me Long Story)

Comment: Don't accept answers before you tried them. Only accept them after they worked for you.

Comment: OK Thanx My Bad It's My First Time On This Forum.Pleasantly Surprised At Such A Quick Response .This Is The First Time I Had To Encounter Such a Problem So Still Bit Of A Novice At Data Recovery and Image Backups

Comment: Please don't write in Title Case As It Is Hard To Read

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can restore a formatted drive completely, given that you have never written anything on it. To recover an entire OS, you need to remove the hard disk from your computer and connect it to a working system as a portable hard disk. This [video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=D1IrvQmWoHU) might help you in doing that.

And to recover the complete partition (if you recover the complete partition, it recovers the complete OS) follow the instructions given in this [link](http://mycrazylaptop.blogspot.in/2014/06/recovering-lost-partition-on-hard-disk.html) (They used active undelete software to recover the partition) although the link provided, explains about recovering a partition, you can use the same method to recover your complete OS.

Edit:- Converting your hard disk to a portable one is not a friendly process, so you can try booting from an external hard disk, to recover the data

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: "Well I Did Install New Windows 7 Which I Have Now Upgraded To Windows 10.It Was Full Format BTW" Lots of overwriting, I doubt it can be recovered completely as you suggest.

Comment: As I mentioned, one can only recover the complete hard disk, given that it is not rewritten!

Answer (score 0):

Restoring files, maybe... Making the OS work? Not a chance.

When you restore files they will not get the proper file name so unless you know exactly what filename each file has you're out of luck. Given that only an IT Pro might (read: very unlikely, but its possible) be able to do this, I doubt you could given that you even thought Windows made backups himself.

If you attempt something like this, be sure that it'll be a months worth project.

Restoring only the files is still very hard to accomplish, and will only work if you haven't worked on the disk since. Every new write to the disk after the format will make it more unlikely that the files can be restored.

Answer (score -1):

There are very narrow chances of data recovery after format. You can try Easeus Data recovery solution. You surely can't restore whole OS but you may be able to restore personal files(If those are not ovwerwritten)

> Fortunately, people always use "Quick Format". As we know, quick format will not hurt the original files in partition. The procedure of format is just to rewrite the table of partition. That means the files are still at the original place after the quick format. This offers opportunities to recover data after format from hard drive/disk for whom want to perform formatted disk data recovery.

Read about it at http://www.easeus.com/resource/recover-data-after-format.htm

Comment: Even Recovering Files Would Be Victory For Me.The Important Files Are Actually PDF Ones And Search Histories On Various Browsers.If I Can Recover Adobe Reader And The Browsers That Would Even Do.Recovering The Entire OS With All My Personal Settings Would Be An Ideal Situation

Comment: You can try any data recovery solution. Because while windows installation quick format is performed. But as you have already installed OS over it so chances are files are already overwritten.

Comment: I May Have Installed A new OS But Apart From Chrome Browser Nothing New Was Added And A Good Portion Of My C Drive Is Still Unused.I Don't Think They Should Be Overwritten.Aren't Files Overwritten When Their Is Not Enough Disk Space Left

Comment: Imagine you have 100GB partition and 50GB data. Do you have 50GB space free? you may not, because other 50GB also might be full but there is no file reference link for that data. So after format it is all full but no file links. So OS has no priority which data to delete.

Comment: OK Thanx But Still Gonna Give Data Recovery A Try.There Are Methods To Recover Overwritten Data Mentioned In Various Blogs